# Deleting shallow nested Comment class returns error "Couldn't find Comment without an ID" (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I have a basic Rails App and I have shallow nested my Comments class within Posts. Post is nested within Topics. I'm trying to delete a comment using the destroy action and come up with error "Couldn't find Comment without an ID"

Error Message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /posts/46/comments
Couldn't find Comment without an ID

CommentsController#destroy

def destroy
  **@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])**
authorize @post
authorize @comment

if @comment.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Comment was removed."
```

routes.rb

```
resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index] 
  end

resources :posts, only: [] do 
  resource :comments, only: [:destroy, :create, :new]
end
```

comments_controller

```
def destroy
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

authorize @post
authorize @comment

if @comment.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Comment was removed."
  redirect_to :action => 'destroy'
else
  flash[:error] = "Comment couldn't be deleted. Try again."
  redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
end
end
```

Note, I have set a before_action to define @post

```
@post =  Post.find( params[:post_id])
```

I have tried looking for ways to delete a current_session instead of looking for a comment id with no luck.

My guess it that there's no id being attached to the comment, but I cannot understand why according to my routes. When I rake routes, I get

```
           post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)         comments#create
       new_post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)     comments#new
                         DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)         comments#destroy
```

Perhaps the issue is there isn't a /:id after DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id?

This is my first rails app and I'm relatively new to Ruby so I would appreciate any help. Thank you again!

**Solution:**

1. pluralize resources: comments to allow for :id creation.
2. Link to the correct comment id when deleting

Our Rails generated comments route method takes a hash argument as its paramter to produce query params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julia,

Welcome to the Rails community!

You're absolutely correct; if you want to delete a single comment, your route will need to accept an :id for comment. However, you currently have it set up as a `resource :comments`. You'll actually want to use `resources :comments` so Rails knows you have more than one comment.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! The singular resoure was exactly why my my route wasn't creating an :id. Glad to be a part of such a supportive community!

Comment: My pleasure. If you don't mind, go ahead and mark this question resolved and select the best answer from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in assuming that the reason is a missing `:id` parameter.

The method you have will destroy a singular comment that is found using: `@post.comments.find(params[:id])`.

Because the `:id` is not sent in, the method doesn't know which comment to destroy.

If deleting a single comment is what you wanted to do, you'll need to modify your paths accordingly and `DELETE` to `/posts/:post_id/comments/:id`.

If you want to delete all the comments for a post, you can modify your method to:

```
@comments = @post.comments

if @comments.destroy
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you Drenmi! I had wanted to delete a singular comment but wasn't feeding an :id.